# Pycharm Warnings: Expected 'collection.iterable', got iterator instead

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a code like below in Python 2.7 in Pycharm 2018.3

```
dep_services = ['fdb']

for s in reversed(dep_services): # This line is throwing warning
    print s
```

Pycharm is showing me a warning `Expected 'collection.iterable', got iterator instead`

Can some one let me know why this is a warning and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: I couldnt reproduse in pycharm 2019.1.2

Comment: It shows that pointing at what piece of code exactly?

Comment: If you have a virtual environment stored in your project make sure to mark it excluded by right-clicking on the venv folder -> mark directory as ... -> excluded. Optionally invalidate caches after it with File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to explicitly convert your reverse iterator to a list:

```
for s in list(reversed(dep_services)): # This line is throwing warning
    print s
```

The reverse method returns a reverse_iterator:

```
print type(reversed([1,2,3]))
print type(list(reversed([1,2,3])))

>>> <class 'list_reverseiterator'>
>>> <class 'list'>
```

Comment: This will use more memory and be slower than only using reversed, since it copies the list again.

Comment: Indeed, but I think that could be the reason PyCharm throws a warning.

Comment: Since AFAIA it's a rather nonsensical warning, it's probably more useful to add an appropriate `# noinspection` line instead.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer because of what @mousetail said. It doesn't make sense to make your code _worse_ just to avoid an IDE warning. It's the (incorrect) warning that should be fixed instead.